# Removing external link by product description in All-Import for Woocommerce

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I have to remove external URL from product description, this is an example:

Powerbank for videocamera Canon NB-5L: https://www.esseshop.it/caricabatterie-universale-da-auto-rete-fotocamera-videocamera-p-4452.html

So I have to remove with regex every substring that starts with http and ends with .html or .htm

```
$str = "Powerbank for videocamera Canon NB-5L: https://www.esseshop.it/caricabatterie-universale-da-auto-rete-fotocamera-videocamera-p-4452.html";

preg_replace('(http)|(.html)|(.htm)', '$1', $str, 1);
```

Comment: `substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "https"));`

Comment: @Max.P. Note that the selected answer does not take into account if the substring ends with .html or .htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching it to any URL starting with `http:` or `https:`

```
https?:\S*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhVcIg/1)**

PHP code demo,

```
$str = "Powerbank for videocamera Canon NB-5L: https://www.esseshop.it/caricabatterie-universale-da-auto-rete-fotocamera-videocamera-p-4452.html";
echo preg_replace('/https?:\S*/', '', $str, 1);
```

Prints,

```
Powerbank for videocamera Canon NB-5L:
```

Comment: @Max.P.: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `(http)|(.html)|(.htm)` uses an alternation with 3 capturing groups and in the code uses group 1 as the replacement. Note to escape the dot to match it literally.

If the url should end with htm or html, you could use:

`\bhttps?:\S+\.html?\b`

**Explanation**

- `\bhttps?:` Word boundary `\b` to prevent http being part of a longer matched word
- `\S+` Match 1+ times not a whitespace character
- `\.html?\b` Match a dot followed by `htm` and an optional `l`. At the end a word boundary to prevent html? being part of a longer matched word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKkFsA/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/4DP3c)